# proving that $\mathcal{M}\models\forall x\phi\wedge\psi\implies\mathcal{M}\models\forall x(\phi\wedge\psi)$

Tags: solution-verification, first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm trying to prove (or disprove, although I think this is correct) that $$\mathcal{M}\models\forall x\phi\wedge\psi\implies\mathcal{M}\models\forall x(\phi\wedge\psi)$$

I think I was able to do so, but there are 2 parts of my proof where I'm a little skeptical it is correct. My proof goes as follows:

---

Assume that $\mathcal{M}\models\forall x\phi\wedge\psi$ this means that $\mathcal{M}\models\phi(x)$ for all interpretations of $x$ and $\mathcal{M}\models \psi$. If $x$ is not in the formula $\psi$, then $\mathcal{M}\models\forall x(\phi\wedge\psi)$.

(1) if $x$ is in the formula $\psi$ change all it's ocuurences for a new variable $x'$ that is not in either $\psi$ or $\phi$ and get a new formula $\psi'$.

then $\mathcal M \models \psi\iff \mathcal M \models \psi'$ and, as such we have that $$\mathcal M\models\forall x(\phi\wedge\psi')$$
witch implies that $$\mathcal M\models\forall x(\phi\wedge\psi)$$
as the formulas $\psi$ and $\psi'$ are equivalent.

---

My question is, is this correct? I'm I allowed to just assume that $x$ is not in $\psi$ by doing (1)?

Comment: what convention are you using to define $\models$? with the standard meaning of $\models$, the relation $M\models\theta$ is not defined when $\theta$ is a formula with free variables. so with that usage, it only makes sense to write $M\models \forall x\phi\wedge\psi$ if $\psi$ has no free variables.

Comment: That is indeed true. But now that you mention that, does it make sense to define $\mathcal M \models \phi$ iff $\mathcal M \models \phi(\bar a)$ for any interpretation of free variables $\bar a$? I think I've seen this somewhere. @AtticusStonestrom

Comment: Typically, $\models$ applied to a non-closed formula means that you should take the universal closure, if it allows non-closed formulae at all (if it doesn't, then this would be almost trivial). Unless you use some other convention, this boils down to showing that universal quantification distributes over conjunction.